# Where is my local App Engine datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I find where my local development datastore is located? I am using the *Python SDK* and *Linux*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it depends on if you got Java or Python SDK.

For Python, here's what the instructions say from Google:
"The web server prints the location of the datastore file it is using to the terminal when it starts up. You can make a copy of the file, then restore them later to reset the datastore to a known state. Be sure to restart the web server after replacing the datastore file.

To change the location used for the datastore file, use the --datastore_path option:

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/tmp/myapp_datastore myapp
```

more info here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html

Answer (score 11):

I'm using Windows 7 with the Python SDK. My local datastore is located at

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\dev_appserver.datastore
```

Comment: On Windows XP with the Python SDK, the local datastore is located at `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Local Settings\Temp\dev_appserver.datastore`

Answer (score 6):

To find the file location for the local AppEngine datastore on MacOSX/Python, you can run the following command:

`dev_appserver.py -help`

Mine was at something like:

`/var/folders/uP/uP1GHkGKGqO7QPq+eGMmb++++TI/-Tmp-/dev_appserver.datastore`

Comment: this also worked nicely on windows. my path was C:\Windows\Temp\dev_appserver.datastore.

Comment: On the latest GAE, the datastore directory is `appengine.[PROJECT_NAME].[USER]`

Answer (score 6):

I think a lot of the answers on this page are out of date. Under the current Python dev kit (1.8.6) on Windows 7 I eventually found the datastore at:

```
c:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine.[appname]\datastore.db
```

I couldn't find this info in anything `dev_appserver.py` printed out, either with normal startup options or with `--help`. On other OSes you might try searching for a file called `datastore.db`.

Comment: For the latest release of the Pyhton SDK this is the correct answer now. The other answers are only still relevant if you are using an Old version of the SDK.

Answer (score 4):

For Python u can make access to datastore admin interface path:' /_ah/'
or

add the app handler to app.yaml

```
- url: /admin/.*
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/admin
  login: admin
```

and access it at /admin/

Answer (score 4):

I use OS X Mavericks (10.9), Python 2.7.5, and Google App Engine SDK 1.9.3 (Python).
None of the above worked for me, however, referencing @alsmola's answer, I executed `sudo find / | grep datastore.db` and found the file in `/private/var/folders/vw/7w1zhkls4gb1wd8r160c36300000gn/T/appengine.YYYY.XXXXX/datastore.db` (`YYYY` is the project name, `XXXXX` is my username).

Answer (score 2):

Since it's top question on Google search and I spent quite amount of time searching for an answer I'll say that on Windows/Java mix DB file called `local_db.bin`.

Answer (score 0):

With Maven the files are sitting here:

```
target/{buildName}/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll restate a solution to getting permanent datastore as it worked for me (circa Feb 2017), running GoogleAppEngineLauncher on OS X v10.10.

- Create the folder path for permanent datastore
- In GAEL, click on the project in question e.g. PROJECTNAME
- Click Edit-Application Settings
- in Extra Flags field:

  --datastore_path=/Users/foo/GAE_datastore/PROJECTNAME/datastore.db

Filename has to be included; in my config, datastore.db works.

Having searched all over for GAE datastore path, and head-bonked on dev_appserver.py --datastore_path command line, it was very helpful to find this.

Application Settings under the Edit menu is an odd choice, Google :-)

Answer (score 0):

The default location of the datastore for the platform you're running the app engine on is provided in the README that comes with the platform (at least, in the one for Linux). The README is in `google_appengine_x.x.xx/google_appengine/README`. This is what is says in the Linux'es one:

> --datastore_path=DS_FILE   Path to file to use for storing Datastore file
>                                stub data.
>                                (Default /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore)