# Why previous data's are missing after every run in App Engine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to learn `Google Cloud Storage` with `JAVA` for some days and i was inserting some data in datastore and the inserted data's could be seen from here **//localhost:8080/_ah/admin/** . Now when i stopped this session and again run the backend some weird behavior i saw.
**Case 1:** When i am running it  again my previous data's are gone.
**Case 2:** If i have inserted 4 data's in the datastore in a session and then in the next session 2 or 3 of my previous data are missing.Here in this case not all the data. And also sometimes one data is missing.

I searched for this and i saw that the `local_db.bin` will be created in every run. I prevented it by adding the following condition in VM arguments - `Ddatastore.backing_store=PATH`.
But still i am having inconsistent behavior. Though the local_db.bin file is not being deleted, but the datastore behavior is erratic. (For example sometimes the entities are successfully preserved, and sometimes some of the entities are deleted).**Will this happen when i integrate with my android app**?

Answer (score 1):

During startup, the App Engine dev server displays the location of the datastore file it is using.  I have seen in the past where a different datastore file is used when starting the server each time.

You can copy the datastore file to a location of your choice.  Use the datastore_path flag to inform the dev server which data file to use.  This will allow the dev server to use the same datastore file each startup.

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/data_path/myapp_datastore myapp
```

You should not see random data disappear from your app as you have mentioned.  One thing to keep in mind is that the Google Cloud Datastore uses an eventual consistency model.  So, if you are inserting a new record in the same process as returning a list of all records - you may not see that new record until you refresh the page in your app.

There are ways to force strong consistency by using ancestor queries. More on ancestor queries can be found in the documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Ancestor_queries

Comment: I have edited my post and i did what you are suggesting.

Comment: why are people giving me downvote??Have i asked dumb question!!

Answer (score 1):

In cause you're developing in Java, you've to provide VM arguments like this

```
-Ddatastore.backing_store="/path/to/datastore/file/location/local_db.bin"
```

More here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68225

You can also find another solution for custom datastore location using Java dev server in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339465/custom-datastore-location-on-local-machine-with-app-engine).

Comment: @setubasak Do you run multiple instances of the dev server simultaneously? Also check your dev server logs, maybe you'd find explanation there. I've not run into such issue so far.

Comment: Nope.I did not run multiple instances of the dev server simultaneously.My partner is facing the same problem also.:(

Answer (score 0):

`//localhost:8080/_ah/admin/` shows only data that is used locally on your computer for testing purposes only. It is not linked to the actual Datastore in any way. You should also test your app with actual data after you deploy your app to the App Engine.

Comment: why are people giving me downvote??Have i asked dumb question!!