# Android Studio deletes appengine-generated folder

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, localhost, google-cloud-datastore

Android Studio 2.1.2 deletes `appengine-generated` folder each rerun of the backend module. Making the local debug pretty tiresome (I think it didn't happen in previous versions, but not sure).

How can I make the local DB not to be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26828977/5487258) worked for me.

basically you need to just make sure to store your db file in a different folder than the exploded-app.