# Google App Engine Launcher crashes on mac

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine

My Google App Engine Launcher crashes on my mac with SIGSEGV.

When I run a Python project on the launcher, it starts running. But the launcher crashes when the project receives HTTP communication such as post.

Does the following crash dump says the reason of the crash is a hash function for a font? The same project runs without any problem on another machine. Other projects run on the launcher.

It is 100% reproducible and always same crash message.

I would appreciate any hint.

```
Process:               GoogleAppEngineLauncher [964]
Path:                  /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleAppEngineLauncher
Identifier:            com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher
Version:               1.9.30 (1.9.30.439)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           GoogleAppEngineLauncher [964]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-12-24 09:37:34.140 +0900
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        A37D6515-A732-FEB4-F4F5-6683B95CD3F3


Time Awake Since Boot: 730 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x20:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-000000000001c000 [  108K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleAppEngineLauncher

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: hash


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x9c78bcaf objc_msgSend + 31
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x905bcb82 probeGC + 68
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x905bcb18 -[NSConcreteMapTable objectForKey:] + 45
3   com.apple.UIFoundation          0x92d435bd +[__NSFontTypefaceInfo typefaceInfoForPostscriptName:options:] + 128
4   com.apple.UIFoundation          0x92d4a6a5 __NSGetMetaFontInstance + 1067
5   com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x0000c34e 0x1000 + 45902
6   com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x0000c4a2 0x1000 + 46242
7   com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x0000c5ae 0x1000 + 46510
8   com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x00011319 0x1000 + 66329
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x907332f2 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_2 + 50
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c22dd14 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c22dc5b ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 75
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c22d22c _CFXRegistrationPost + 460
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c22cf66 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 54
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c2269f3 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1715
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c102e22 _CFXNotificationPost + 626
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x905ae1c5 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x906f7942 _performFileHandleSource + 1558
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c17933f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c16aa1b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c169e42 __CFRunLoopRun + 994
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c1697f6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 390
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c16965b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
23  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x933932f1 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 267
24  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x933930f3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 503
25  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x93392eec _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 99
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x9923f512 _DPSNextEvent + 1053
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x9964a0b0 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1057
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x9923ef8b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 121
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x9923412f -[NSApplication run] + 1063
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x991af025 NSApplicationMain + 1630
31  com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x00002600 0x1000 + 5632
32  com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x0000259d 0x1000 + 5533
33  com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x000024c8 0x1000 + 5320
```

- Google App Engine Launcher 1.9.30, latest
- mac os x  10.11.2
- Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by myself.

**The above problem was disappeared when I removed database files made by App Engine Launcher.**

The location of the database files were discussed in the following page.

[Where is my local App Engine datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588817/where-is-my-local-app-engine-datastore)

Checking "Clear database on launch" option did not solved the problem.

Comment: The above works just after the removal of database files and the same problem occurs. Very sticky.