# Google App Engine Launcher crashes on OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, google-app-engine, osx-elcapitan

My Google App Engine Launcher crashes on my mac with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV).

When I run a Python project on the launcher, it starts running but the launcher crashes when the project receives HTTP communication such as POST or GET.

- Google App Engine Launcher 1.9.30 (latest)
- mac os x 10.11.2  (latest)
- Python 2.7.10

The same issue as this one [Google App Engine Launcher crashes on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446267/google-app-engine-launcher-crashes-on-mac/) however deleting the datastore (which resolved that post) doesn't help.

Running it on command line works fine

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

Below is the crash report in case it is of help.

```
Process:               GoogleAppEngineLauncher [9026]
Path:                  /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleAppEngineLauncher
Identifier:            com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher
Version:               1.9.30 (1.9.30.439)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           GoogleAppEngineLauncher [9026]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-12-30 15:43:56.720 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        59B8A36A-600F-2FB1-9253-7E2985E2D320


Time Awake Since Boot: 21000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x20:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-000000000001c000 [  108K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleAppEngineLauncher

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: hash


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x9e09acaf objc_msgSend + 31
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x9972eb82 probeGC + 68
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x9972eb18 -[NSConcreteMapTable objectForKey:] + 45
3   com.apple.UIFoundation          0x9abd95bd +[__NSFontTypefaceInfo typefaceInfoForPostscriptName:options:] + 128
4   com.apple.UIFoundation          0x9abe06a5 __NSGetMetaFontInstance + 1067
5   com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x0000c34e 0x1000 + 45902
6   com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x0000c4a2 0x1000 + 46242
7   com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x0000c5ae 0x1000 + 46510
8   com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x00011319 0x1000 + 66329
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x998a52f2 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_2 + 50
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x962cad14 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x962cac5b ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 75
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x962ca22c _CFXRegistrationPost + 460
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x962c9f66 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 54
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x962c39f3 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1715
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9619fe22 _CFXNotificationPost + 626
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x997201c5 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92
17  com.apple.Foundation            0x99869942 _performFileHandleSource + 1558
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9621633f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x96207a1b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x96206e42 __CFRunLoopRun + 994
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x962067f6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 390
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9620665b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
23  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x949ea2f1 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 267
24  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x949ea0f3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 503
25  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x949e9eec _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 99
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x93d75512 _DPSNextEvent + 1053
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x941800b0 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1057
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x93d74f8b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 121
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x93d6a12f -[NSApplication run] + 1063
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x93ce5025 NSApplicationMain + 1630
31  com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x00002600 0x1000 + 5632
32  com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x0000259d 0x1000 + 5533
33  com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher  0x000024c8 0x1000 + 5320
```